# How to display jpg image by ImageMagicK in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, imagemagick

I have got a hard time to display jpg file at VIEW class by ImageMagicK in MFC.

The following code are my code. the problem is looking as following
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmq8x.jpg)

```
void CTestview::DoDisplayImage(void)
{
    CDC *pDC = GetDC();

    if (fileposition != NULL)
        AfxMessageBox(fileposition);

    char m_szAppPath[255];
    //m_szAppPath = (char) * fileposition;

    (void)MagickCore::SetClientPath(fileposition);
    InitializeMagick(fileposition);
    MagickCore::RegisterStaticModules();

    // Parse command line for standard shell commands, DDE, file open

    Image m_Image;
    m_Image.read(fileposition);

    /*
    char m_szAppPath[255];
    (void) MagickCore::SetClientPath(m_szAppPath);
    InitializeMagick(m_szAppPath);
    MagickCore::RegisterStaticModules();

    // Parse command line for standard shell commands, DDE, file open
    CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
    ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);
    Image master;
    master.read("D:\\work\\mfc_test5\\q1.jpg");
    */

    if (pDC != NULL && m_Image.isValid())
    {
        CRect rectClient;
        GetClientRect(rectClient);

        // Clear the background
        pDC->FillSolidRect(rectClient, pDC->GetBkColor());

        // Set up the Windows bitmap header
        BITMAPINFOHEADER bmi;
        bmi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);    // Size of structure
        bmi.biWidth = m_Image.columns();          // Bitmaps width in pixels
        bmi.biHeight = (-1)*m_Image.rows();       // Bitmaps height n pixels
        bmi.biPlanes = 1;                         // Number of planes in the image
        bmi.biBitCount = 32;                      // The number of bits per pixel
        bmi.biCompression = BI_RGB;               // The type of compression used
        bmi.biSizeImage = 0;                      // The size of the image in bytes
        bmi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;                  // Horizontal resolution
        bmi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;                  // Veritical resolution
        bmi.biClrUsed = 0;                        // Number of colors actually used
        bmi.biClrImportant = 0;                   // Colors most important

                                                                // Extract the pixels from Magick++ image object and convert to a DIB section
        PixelPacket *pPixels = m_Image.getPixels(0, 0, m_Image.columns(), m_Image.rows());


        RGBQUAD *prgbaDIB = 0;
        HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateDIBSection
            (
                pDC->m_hDC,            // handle to device context
                (BITMAPINFO *)&bmi,    // pointer to structure containing bitmap size, format, and color data
                DIB_RGB_COLORS,        // color data type indicator: RGB values or palette indices
                (void**)&prgbaDIB,     // pointer to variable to receive a pointer to the bitmap's bit values
                NULL,                  // optional handle to a file mapping object
                0                      // offset to the bitmap bit values within the file mapping object
                );

        if (!hBitmap)
            return;

        unsigned long nPixels = m_Image.columns() * m_Image.rows();
        RGBQUAD *pDestPixel = prgbaDIB;
        // Transfer pixels, scaling to Quantum
        /*
        for( unsigned long nPixelCount = nPixels; nPixelCount ; nPixelCount-- )
        {
        pDestPixel->rgbRed = MagickCore::GetPixelRed(m_Image.constImage(),pPixels)/257;
        pDestPixel->rgbGreen = MagickCore::GetPixelGreen(m_Image.constImage(),pPixels)/257;
        pDestPixel->rgbBlue = MagickCore::GetPixelBlue(m_Image.constImage(),pPixels)/257;
        pDestPixel->rgbReserved = 0;
        ++pDestPixel;
        pPixels+=MagickCore::GetPixelChannels(m_Image.constImage());
        }
        */
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            pPixels->blue = (BYTE)i;
            pPixels->green = (BYTE)i;
            pPixels->red = (BYTE)i;
            pPixels->opacity = 0;
            pPixels++;
        }

        // Now copy the bitmap to device.
        HDC     hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(pDC->m_hDC);
        SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);
        BitBlt(pDC->m_hDC, 0, 0, m_Image.columns(), m_Image.rows(), hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        DeleteObject(hMemDC);
    }
}
```

Especially, at the following code does not sure.
What should I do for solving this problem?

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i++ )
{
    pPixels->blue  = (BYTE)i;
    pPixels->green = (BYTE)i;
    pPixels->red   = (BYTE)i;
    pPixels->opacity = 0;
    pPixels++;
}
```

Would you please help me how do I do for solving this problem?
As you can see, the output image has black.

Comment: @Spg: if you don't mind, would you please help me?